# How can I extract volume names and associated IPs from variable files with two loops in my Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have constructed a variable files like below. It is made up by a volume and multiple IP's underneath. I have tried a playbook as shown below to extract volumes and associated IP's to two different variables. My first question is what variables should be defined and used here, list/dict type?

After that, I will have another task to use these two variable.

The result of my playbook can only use one loop and print each one of volume along with all it's IP's(not individual IP) . My second question is, What second element should be as 2nd item that 2nd loop can loop on?

**variable file:vars_file.yml**

```
---
volumes:
  - volumename: volume1
    client:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.1.1.2
  - volumename: volume2
    client: 2.2.2.2
  - volumename: volume3
    client: 3.3.3.3
```

**my playbook:**

```
---
- name: print volumes
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - vars_file.yml
  tasks:
    - name: display volumes
      debug:
        msg: "volume: {{ item.volumename }} client: {{ item.client }}"
      loop: "{{ volumes }}"`
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be consistent in the structure of your data. In your example, `client` is sometimes a string, and sometimes a list. Make it a list in all cases:

```
volumes:
  - volumename: volume1
    client:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.1.1.2
  - volumename: volume2
    client:
      - 2.2.2.2
  - volumename: volume3
    client:
      - 3.3.3.3
```

Now we can use the `subelements` filter:

```
- name: print volumes
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    volumes:
      - volumename: volume1
        client:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.1.1.2
      - volumename: volume2
        client:
          - 2.2.2.2
      - volumename: volume3
        client:
          - 3.3.3.3
  tasks:
    - name: display volumes
      debug:
        msg: "volume: {{ item.0.volumename }} client: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ volumes|subelements('client') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.volumename }}"
```

Running the above playbook produces:

```
TASK [display volumes] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=volume1) => {
    "msg": "volume: volume1 client: 1.1.1.1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=volume1) => {
    "msg": "volume: volume1 client: 1.1.1.2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=volume2) => {
    "msg": "volume: volume2 client: 2.2.2.2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=volume3) => {
    "msg": "volume: volume3 client: 3.3.3.3"
}
```

Comment: This was what I would like to achieve. One follow-up if you don't mind.
How can I assign each one of volumenames, and clients to two different respective list variables? The following tasks will need and process them. Thank you!! @larsks

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking. That's probably worth opening a new question so that you can provide an example.